# sort Pandas dataframe with NaT values on top

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, numpy

Im trying to sort a pandas dataframe with NaT values on top. I'm using the df.sort_values function:

```
df=df.sort_values(by='date_of_last_hoorah_given')
```

Its working fine and I'm getting a sorted dataframe with NaT values in the bottom

```
    date_of_last_hoorah_given                              email   first_name  \
16 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              mindy.lyndi@hoorah.io        Mindy   
29 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              judi.seward@hoorah.io         Judi   
7  2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000                  chao.an@hoorah.io         Chao   
21 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              bala.harish@hoorah.io         Bala   
12 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000            pushpa.swaran@hoorah.io       Pushpa   
30 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000       sparrow.freespirit@hoorah.io      Sparrow   
28 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000         sanjeev.prasanna@hoorah.io      Sanjeev   
27 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000     twinklenose.snowleaf@hoorah.io  Twinklenose   
25 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000       sweetgaze.sugarshy@hoorah.io    Sweetgaze   
23 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            shreya.sarika@hoorah.io       Shreya   
19 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000              jiahao.dong@hoorah.io       Jiahao   
15 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            jannine.tyson@hoorah.io       Janine   
14 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                arlo.reed@hoorah.io         Arlo   
0  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000         aditya.hariharan@hoorah.io       Aditya   
11 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000        shirley.madalitso@hoorah.io      Shirley   
2  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             minerva.jena@hoorah.io     Minerva    
3  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             colby.brandi@hoorah.io        Colby   
13 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            beverly.cohen@hoorah.io      Beverly   
6  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             guanting.jun@hoorah.io     Guanting   
5  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                  chen.tu@hoorah.io         Chen   
18 2016-12-22 10:55:03.474683                  fen.lin@hoorah.io          Fen   
9  2016-12-23 07:36:08.000000             kourtney.pam@hoorah.io     Kourtney   
10 2016-12-23 14:30:55.206581             kailee.alfie@hoorah.io       Kailee   
4  2016-12-24 07:36:08.000000                jing.chao@hoorah.io        Jing    
31 2016-12-24 16:02:28.945809               rich.oswin@hoorah.io         Rich   
24 2016-12-25 07:36:08.000000           ganesh.vasanta@hoorah.io       Ganesh   
8  2016-12-26 07:36:08.000000               xia.yaling@hoorah.io          Xia   
20 2016-12-27 07:36:08.000000              kinley.joan@hoorah.io       Kinley   
22 2016-12-28 07:36:08.000000   honeygleam.dazzlesmile@hoorah.io   Honeygleam   
26 2016-12-28 15:29:48.629929             indira.padma@hoorah.io       Indira   
17 2016-12-29 02:27:11.125078             ileen.gaynor@hoorah.io        Ileen   
32 2016-12-29 15:38:02.335296            ragnar.lestat@hoorah.io       Ragnar   
1                         NaT  flitterbeam.clovergaze@hoorah.com  Flitterbeam
```

but when I try to get it on top with the following piece of code:

```
df=df.sort_values(by='date_of_last_hoorah_given',ascending=[1,0])
```

Im getting a valueError: Length of ascending (2) != length of by (1)
Full stack trace given below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-948a8354aeeb> in <module>()
      1 cd = ClientData(1)
----> 2 cd.get_inactive_users()

<ipython-input-106-ed230054ea86> in get_inactive_users(self)
    346             inactive_users_result.append(user_dict)
    347         df=pd.DataFrame(inactive_users_result)
--> 348         df=df.sort_values(by='date_of_last_hoorah_given',ascending=[1,0])
    349         print(df)

C:\Users\aditya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
   3126         if com.is_sequence(ascending) and len(by) != len(ascending):
   3127             raise ValueError('Length of ascending (%d) != length of by (%d)' %
-> 3128                              (len(ascending), len(by)))
   3129         if len(by) > 1:
   3130             from pandas.core.groupby import _lexsort_indexer

ValueError: Length of ascending (2) != length of by (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use 2 values in `ascending=[1,0]`, because sort only one column:

If need descending sort use `False`, `True` is by default:

```
df=df.sort_values(by='date_of_last_hoorah_given',ascending=False)
print (df)
     date_of_last_hoorah_given                              email   first_name
1                          NaT  flitterbeam.clovergaze@hoorah.com  Flitterbeam
32  2016-12-29 15:38:02.335296            ragnar.lestat@hoorah.io       Ragnar
17  2016-12-29 02:27:11.125078             ileen.gaynor@hoorah.io        Ileen
26  2016-12-28 15:29:48.629929             indira.padma@hoorah.io       Indira
22  2016-12-28 07:36:08.000000   honeygleam.dazzlesmile@hoorah.io   Honeygleam
20  2016-12-27 07:36:08.000000              kinley.joan@hoorah.io       Kinley
8   2016-12-26 07:36:08.000000               xia.yaling@hoorah.io          Xia
24  2016-12-25 07:36:08.000000           ganesh.vasanta@hoorah.io       Ganesh
31  2016-12-24 16:02:28.945809               rich.oswin@hoorah.io         Rich
4   2016-12-24 07:36:08.000000                jing.chao@hoorah.io         Jing
10  2016-12-23 14:30:55.206581             kailee.alfie@hoorah.io       Kailee
9   2016-12-23 07:36:08.000000             kourtney.pam@hoorah.io     Kourtney
18  2016-12-22 10:55:03.474683                  fen.lin@hoorah.io          Fen
3   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             colby.brandi@hoorah.io        Colby
5   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                  chen.tu@hoorah.io         Chen
6   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             guanting.jun@hoorah.io     Guanting
13  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            beverly.cohen@hoorah.io      Beverly
2   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             minerva.jena@hoorah.io      Minerva
11  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000        shirley.madalitso@hoorah.io      Shirley
0   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000         aditya.hariharan@hoorah.io       Aditya
14  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                arlo.reed@hoorah.io         Arlo
15  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            jannine.tyson@hoorah.io       Janine
...
...
```

If need sort by 2 columns, first ascending and second descending:

```
df=df.sort_values(by=['date_of_last_hoorah_given', 'email'],ascending=[True, False])
```

If need ascending sort with `NaN` first one possible solution is [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) splited DataFrame:

```
df.date_of_last_hoorah_given = pd.to_datetime(df.date_of_last_hoorah_given)
df=df.sort_values(by='date_of_last_hoorah_given')
mask = df.date_of_last_hoorah_given.isnull()
print (pd.concat([df[mask], df[~mask]]))
    date_of_last_hoorah_given                              email   first_name
1                         NaT  flitterbeam.clovergaze@hoorah.com  Flitterbeam
16 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              mindy.lyndi@hoorah.io        Mindy
29 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              judi.seward@hoorah.io         Judi
7  2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000                  chao.an@hoorah.io         Chao
21 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              bala.harish@hoorah.io         Bala
12 2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000            pushpa.swaran@hoorah.io       Pushpa
5  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                  chen.tu@hoorah.io         Chen
6  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             guanting.jun@hoorah.io     Guanting
13 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            beverly.cohen@hoorah.io      Beverly
3  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             colby.brandi@hoorah.io        Colby
11 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000        shirley.madalitso@hoorah.io      Shirley
0  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000         aditya.hariharan@hoorah.io       Aditya
14 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                arlo.reed@hoorah.io         Arlo
2  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             minerva.jena@hoorah.io      Minerva
19 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000              jiahao.dong@hoorah.io       Jiahao
23 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            shreya.sarika@hoorah.io       Shreya
15 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            jannine.tyson@hoorah.io       Janine
25 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000       sweetgaze.sugarshy@hoorah.io    Sweetgaze
27 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000     twinklenose.snowleaf@hoorah.io  Twinklenose
28 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000         sanjeev.prasanna@hoorah.io      Sanjeev
30 2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000       sparrow.freespirit@hoorah.io      Sparrow
18 2016-12-22 10:55:03.474683                  fen.lin@hoorah.io          Fen
9  2016-12-23 07:36:08.000000             kourtney.pam@hoorah.io     Kourtney
10 2016-12-23 14:30:55.206581             kailee.alfie@hoorah.io       Kailee
4  2016-12-24 07:36:08.000000                jing.chao@hoorah.io         Jing
...
...
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that `NaT` is maximal when sorting and therefore will always come last.  In order to sort by ascending date while putting `NaT` in front or on top, you need to sort with two conditions.

`np.lexsort` will sort an array by any number of conditions and return a sorting slice similar to `np.argsort`

Also note that I will put the `notnull` condition last in the array of conditions passed to `np.lexsort`.  `np.lexsort` sorts the last elements first... I don't know why, but that's the way it is.

So we should sort by `df.date_of_last_hoorah_given.notnull()` first  because those that aren't null will have a value of `True` which is greater that `False` in a sorting context.  Then we can sort by the rest of the dates.

```
dates = df.date_of_last_hoorah_given
sort_slice = np.lexsort([dates.values, dates.notnull().values])
df.iloc[sort_slice]
```

OR! as OP said in comments, this gives the same thing and is much more straight forward

```
df.sort_values('date_of_last_hoorah_given', na_position='first')

     date_of_last_hoorah_given                              email   first_name
1                          NaT  flitterbeam.clovergaze@hoorah.com  Flitterbeam
16  2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              mindy.lyndi@hoorah.io        Mindy
29  2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              judi.seward@hoorah.io         Judi
7   2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000                  chao.an@hoorah.io         Chao
21  2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000              bala.harish@hoorah.io         Bala
12  2016-12-19 07:36:08.000000            pushpa.swaran@hoorah.io       Pushpa
30  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000       sparrow.freespirit@hoorah.io      Sparrow
28  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000         sanjeev.prasanna@hoorah.io      Sanjeev
27  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000     twinklenose.snowleaf@hoorah.io  Twinklenose
25  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000       sweetgaze.sugarshy@hoorah.io    Sweetgaze
23  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            shreya.sarika@hoorah.io       Shreya
19  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000              jiahao.dong@hoorah.io       Jiahao
15  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            jannine.tyson@hoorah.io       Janine
14  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                arlo.reed@hoorah.io         Arlo
0   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000         aditya.hariharan@hoorah.io       Aditya
11  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000        shirley.madalitso@hoorah.io      Shirley
2   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             minerva.jena@hoorah.io      Minerva
3   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             colby.brandi@hoorah.io        Colby
13  2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000            beverly.cohen@hoorah.io      Beverly
6   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000             guanting.jun@hoorah.io     Guanting
5   2016-12-22 07:36:08.000000                  chen.tu@hoorah.io         Chen
18  2016-12-22 10:55:03.474683                  fen.lin@hoorah.io          Fen
9   2016-12-23 07:36:08.000000             kourtney.pam@hoorah.io     Kourtney
10  2016-12-23 14:30:55.206581             kailee.alfie@hoorah.io       Kailee
4   2016-12-24 07:36:08.000000                jing.chao@hoorah.io         Jing
31  2016-12-24 16:02:28.945809               rich.oswin@hoorah.io         Rich
24  2016-12-25 07:36:08.000000           ganesh.vasanta@hoorah.io       Ganesh
8   2016-12-26 07:36:08.000000               xia.yaling@hoorah.io          Xia
20  2016-12-27 07:36:08.000000              kinley.joan@hoorah.io       Kinley
22  2016-12-28 07:36:08.000000   honeygleam.dazzlesmile@hoorah.io   Honeygleam
26  2016-12-28 15:29:48.629929             indira.padma@hoorah.io       Indira
17  2016-12-29 02:27:11.125078             ileen.gaynor@hoorah.io        Ileen
32  2016-12-29 15:38:02.335296            ragnar.lestat@hoorah.io       Ragnar
```

Comment: Thanks piRquared, I seemed to get the same output when I pushed a na_position='first' to the function `df=df.sort_values(by='date_of_last_hoorah_given',na_position='first')`

Comment: @AdityaHariharan hey!  I didn't know that.  Right on, thx for letting me know.  I like it when I learn stuff.

Comment: Now I'm facing the problem that when I convert this dataframe to a dictionary using the following piece of code `df.T.to_dict().values()`, all the sorting goes to waste

Comment: `reset_index(drop=True)` will give you a fresh index sorted from `0` to whatever.  Then `to_dict` should keep that new index.